# Linux Kernel Error: scripts/kconfig/qconf.h:105 extra qualification 'ConfigList'

Tags: linux-kernel

I am making system call in my **CentOS 6 kernel version is linux-2.6** and while making `configuration image by

```
make bzImage`
```

I found the following error

```
scripts/kconfig/qconf.h:105 extra qualification 'ConfigList'
```

It would be great to know where I am going wrong.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

for
scripts/kconfig/qconf.h:127: error: extra qualification ConfigList:: on member updateMenuList

@@ -124,7 +124,7 @@ public:
    void setParentMenu(void);

```
template <class P>
```

-   void ConfigList::updateMenuList(P*, struct menu*);//remove this

- void updateMenuList(P*, struct menu*);//add this

  bool updateAll;

_